# how to show and hide menu with session in php

Tags: php

I have session after login. problem, when the session does not exist, an error will appear:

```
Notice: Undefined index: client-rajabot in .......
```

I want, when the session I can. the menu "mypage" will appear, and when there is no such session, the "mypage" is not displayed.

I expect support for the session checking code snippets. 
thank you.the session name = `$ _SESSION ['client-rajabot']`.

and I set it on the menu include code like this:

```
<div id="navbar">
<ul>  
    <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Home")echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>><a href="index">Home</a>
    <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Register")echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>><a href="register">Register</a>
    <?php
        session_start();
        if($_SESSION['client-rajabot']!='' || $_SESSION['client-rajabot'] != null)
        {
        echo "<li if ($thisPage==ClientPage) id=\currentpage\><a href=client-page>MyPage</a>"; 
        }
    ?>       
    <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Topup")echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>><a href="topup">TopUp</a>
    <li<?php if ($thisPage=="Login")echo " id=\"currentpage\""; ?>><a href="login">Login Member</a>
</ul>
```

problem, when the session does not exist, an error will appear:

```
Notice: Undefined index: client-rajabot in .......
```

I want, when the session I can. the menu `"mypage"` will appear, and when there is no such session, the `"mypage"` is not displayed.

I expect support for the session checking code snippets. 
thank you.

Comment: You can't do this:  `echo "<li if ($thisPage==ClientPage) id=\currentpage\><a href=client-page>MyPage</a>"; ` ............

Comment: unless you are using output buffering, the session will never start anyway. That aside, you can check for the existence of a variable with the isset() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
if(isset($_SESSION['client-rajabot']))
```

The condition `$_SESSION['client-rajabot']!=''` that you are using, requires that there is a `$_SESSION['client-rajabot']` to be compared to the empty string. That is why you are getting an error when you haven't set the 'client-rajabot'.

The `isset()` command examines if the variable is set or not. It should be noted that `isset()` returns FALSE if the variable is set to NULL. That means you don't have to check for NULL as well. If there is any reason for the session variable to be a empty string (it shouldn't be) you can use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['client-rajabot']) && $_SESSION['client-rajabot'] != '')
```

That makes sure that there is a session variable and that the variable isn't empty.